# Replacing multiple substrings in a string

Tags: java, strings, array, comparative-review, hash-map

Here are 2 functions defined that do the exactly same thing: take input a template (in which one wants to replace some substrings) and array of strings values (key value pair to replace, such as [subStrToReplace1,value1,subStrToReplace1,value2,.....]) and returns the replaced `String`.

In second function I am iterating over words of the templates and searching for the relevant key if exist in a `HashMap` and then next word. If I want to replace a word with some substring, which I again want to replace with some other key in values, I need to iterate over template twice.

I would like to know which one should I use and why. Any better alternative than these are also welcome.

1st function

```
public static String populateTemplate1(String template, String... values) {
        String populatedTemplate = template;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
            populatedTemplate = populatedTemplate.replace(values[i], values[i + 1]);
        }

        return populatedTemplate;    
    }
```

2nd function

```
   public static String populateTemplate2(String template, String... values) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
            map.put(values[i],values[i+1]);
        }      

        StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (String word : map.keySet()) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                regex.append('|');
            }
            regex.append(Pattern.quote(word));
        }
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString());

        int N0OfIterationOverTemplate =2;
        // Pattern allowing to extract only the words
        // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
        StringBuilder populatedTemplate=new StringBuilder();;

        String temp_template=template;

        while(N0OfIterationOverTemplate!=0){
        populatedTemplate = new StringBuilder();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp_template);
        int fromIndex = 0;
        while (matcher.find(fromIndex)) {
            // The start index of the current word
            int startIdx = matcher.start();
            if (fromIndex < startIdx) {
                // Add what we have between two words
                populatedTemplate.append(temp_template, fromIndex, startIdx);
            }
            // The current word
            String word = matcher.group();
            // Replace the word by itself or what we have in the map
            // populatedTemplate.append(map.getOrDefault(word, word));

            if (map.get(word) == null) {
                populatedTemplate.append(word);
            }
            else {
                populatedTemplate.append(map.get(word));
            }

            // Start the next find from the end index of the current word
            fromIndex = matcher.end();
        }
        if (fromIndex < temp_template.length()) {
            // Add the remaining sub String
            populatedTemplate.append(temp_template, fromIndex, temp_template.length());
        }

        N0OfIterationOverTemplate--;
        temp_template=populatedTemplate.toString();
    }
        return populatedTemplate.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Variable naming

`N0OfIterationOverTemplate` is not only a mouthful, but anyone will also start to wonder about that weird spelling choice of combining a zero `0` with a capital `O` together. `countIterationOverTemplate` is much easier to follow.

#### `null` handling

Erm, consider how you want to handle potential `null` values safely.

#### Biggest difference

Test case: `"template", "a", "b", "a", "c"`

In the first method, it immediately replaces the `"a"`s with `"b"`s, so the second substitution to `"c"` is effectively a no-op. You end up with `"templbte"`.

In the second method, there's ***only one*** substitution being performed, due to how [`Map.put(K, V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) works. Not only that, it's ***indeterministic*** which substitution will happen due to how `HashMap.keySet()` has no predictable iteration order.

#### Interfaces over implementations declaration

This is the least of your concern here given the biggest difference above, but you are highly recommended to declare `map` as a `Map` instead of `HashMap` because where it's used, it does not need to be known about its actual `Map` implementation.